# How to bind simple static string to WPF Label

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a C# .NET 4.5 WPF application, with a  public static class.  Inside that class I have a public static string.  What I want is very simple, I want to bind that static string to a WPF `Label`, so whenever that string is updated, WPF Label will also get updated.

How can I achieve this with simplest and easiest way

Static class below

```
public static class GlobalStats
{
    private static void updateValues()
    {
        srGlobalStatics="example";   
    }
    public static string srGlobalStatics = "";
}
```

I want my WPF Label bound to that particular `srGlobalStatics` string.

Here's my XAML code:

```
<Label Name="lblGlobalStats" Content="lblGlobalStats" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Margin="10,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Isn't this possible ?

I can write a function inside MainWindow.xaml.cs however i don't want to put unnecessary code inside there as much as possible.

Comment: Is it just me or is it just plain wrong for someone with over a 4,000 rep to ask a question in this way?

Comment: @user3910810 When something simple isn't working, it's easy to get angry.  Anger leads to hate.  Hate leads to ... typos.

Comment: Yes i ceased my anger :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer for your first post:

```
 <Label Name="lblGlobalStats" 
 Content="{Binding Source={x:Static wpfApplication1:GlobalStats.srGlobalStatics}}" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

To your second question (raised in comments), assuming you want it all static (as ugly as it is):

```
public static void updateValues()
{
    srGlobalStatics[0] = "changed";
}

public static ObservableCollection<string> srGlobalStatics = 
   new ObservableCollection<string> { "test" };
```

Wpf:

```
<Label Name="lblGlobalStats" 
    Content="{Binding Path=[0], Source={x:Static 
    wpfApplication1:GlobalStats.srGlobalStatics}}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Your class will have to be able to provide property change notifications, which is not possible when using a static class.  If you were able to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` then you'd be able to call `OnPropertyChanged("srGlobalStatics")`, which would fix your problem.

Comment: Ok one more question. If i use ObservableCollection how can i bind it to the label. Assume that i added 1 element to the ObservableCollection and i always update that element. So i want to bind it to index 0

Comment: To your first question http://stackoverflow.com/a/1925798/872413 ... also, I would like to suggest you to try and read a bit more about WPF and bindings, because I don't think you are on 'right track'.

Comment: Edited answer to answer your second question

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (not necessarily the best) way to do this would be to declare your `GlobalStats` class as non-static, set it as your `DataContext`, and finally bind to your string from the XAML source:

```
public class GlobalStats
{
    private string _myLabel;

    public string MyLabel {
        get { return _myLabel; }
        set { _myLabel = value; }
    }
}
```

Then, in your code-behind, have something like this:

```
private GlobalStats_myDataModel = new GlobalStats();

// ...

public MainWindow() {
    // ...
    DataContext = _myDataModel;
```

Finally, your XAML:

```
<Label Name="lblGlobalStats" Content="{Binding Path=MyLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   Margin="10,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: ty for answers. non static answers are floding the stackoverflow. however i really need static solution.

Comment: You may want to re-evaluate your program structure; I don't see any reason you would absolutely have to use a global static string _ever_ in WPF + XAML.

Comment: Well i like static variables and i want to learn how to solve this problem.