# What is a simple, thread safe assignment pattern in C# for issuing unique counter values?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I am not an expert on multi-threading in C#; I want to be sure to *prevent* a race condition that would be a hard surely be a difficult to trigger in testing, while also being nearly impossible to debug.  The requirement (my application is a utility class to be used in a possibly multi-threaded HTTP server, not using IIS or ASP.NET) is that each instance of a class have a unique identifier for that instance.

I would rather *not* use heavy-weight GUIDs to avoid the issue, due to their serialized length, as in an HTML representation.

My question is this:  is the simple pattern to set the `Unique` value in the `Widget` class below a good pattern for this rquirement?  Is there a better, safer pattern that is hopefully not to burdensome to implement?

```
public abstract class Widget : Node
{
    private static int UniqueCount = 0;
    private static object _lock = new object();
    protected int Unique { private set; get; }

    protected Widget() : base()
    {
        // There could be a subtle race condition if this is not thread-safe
        // if it is used with a multi-threaded web server
        lock (_lock)
        {
            UniqueCount += 1;
            Unique = UniqueCount;
        }
    }  

}
```

Comment: What do you mean unique counter values?  Do you have multiple threads that are incrementing a running counter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011908/how-to-easy-make-this-counter-property-thread-safe

Comment: They might, that is the risk, and I don't want any instance to have a unique value shared or assigned another instance due to a race condition between the two assignments.  Now that the code is in the question, it should be more clear.  The shared counter is the static member `UniqueCount`.

Comment: Check my answer (copied from another).  It should answer your question.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate (or the copied answer applies) because this question is not just the inherent possible race in non-atomic  `X = X + 1` type code.  The safe transaction must encompass `X += 1; Y = X;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the `+=` (and related) operations are not threadsafe. When doing simple number increments, just use [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx); it will return the old value and is fully threadsafe:

```
public abstract class Widget : Node
{
    private static int UniqueCount = 0;
    protected int Unique { private set; get; }

    protected Widget() : base()
    {
        Unique = Interlocked.Increment(ref UniqueCount);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer for its beautiful clarity.  I thank you both both folks who answered (at least so far).  I was completely unaware of the existence of the `Interlocked` class in the library.  That is extremely helpful.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ `Interlocked` is awesome; take a look at the other useful methods it has! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011987/598637):

If you're looking to implement the property in such a way that `DoneCounter = DoneCounter + 1` is guaranteed not to be subject to race conditions, it can't be done in the property's implementation.  That operation is not atomic, it actually three distinct steps:

1. Retrieve the value of `DoneCounter`.
2. Add 1
3. Store the result in `DoneCounter`.

You have to guard against the possibility that a context switch could happen in between any of those steps. Locking inside the getter or setter won't help, because that locks scope exists entirely within one of the steps (either 1 or 2).  If you want to make sure all three steps happen together without being interrupted, then your synchronization has to cover all three steps. Which means it has to happen in a context that contains all three of them.  That's probably going to end up being code that does not belong to whatever class contains the `DoneCounter` property.

It is the responsibility of the person using your object to take care of thread safety.  In general, no class that has read/write fields or properties can be made "thread-safe" in this manner.  However, if you can change the class's interface so that setters aren't necessary, then it is possible to make it more thread-safe.  For example, if you know that DoneCounter only increments and decrements, then you could re-implement it like so:

```
private int _doneCounter;
public int DoneCounter { get { return _doneCounter; } }
public void IncrementDoneCounter() { Interlocked.Increment(ref _doneCounter); }
public void DecrementDoneCounter() { Interlocked.Decrement(ref _doneCounter); }
```

Comment: The question is not just the inherent possible race in `X = X + 1` type code.  The safe transaction must encompass `X += 1; Y = X;'.  For this reason, I don't think your old answer applies.

Comment: Why not just use X++ and Y++?  why do you need to synchronize the two?

Comment: I believe that `++` operators with their side effects are a bad idea and I avoid them, in favor of the 'X += 1' type pattern, which has the semantics I want in almost every case.   However, that is irrelevant to the non-atomic of the race condition.  Writeing the code as 'Y = X++' will generate extremely similar non-atomic bytecode if I understand correctly.

Comment: I meant using X++ in the context of my answer.  Interlocked.Increment(ref X).  `Interlocked` is indeed what you want to use for this.

Comment: Okay, based on the other answer, now I understand what you were trying to say.  Thank you.  I will upvote for the information.