# Updating a database from a set accessor: Raise private event?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, multithreading, accessor

I need to update an SQLite database when a class property changes. Here is a poor implementation that demonstrates exactly what needs to be accomplished on a larger scale:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    private bool isFoo;

    internal bool IsFoo
    {
        get { return isFoo; }

        private set
        {
            isFoo = value;
            UpdateDatabase(); // ← This method could take some time.
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDatabase()
    {
        DatabaseClass.Update(this);
    }
}
```

SO user, LukeH, said in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/505604/5183403):

> if two threads access [a property] simultaneously, the getter will
>   briefly block the second thread until it returns the object to the
>   first thread...

**Current Direction**

I don't want to block access to the property. If I implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, my code will either be inconsistent in how it saves data or turn `DatabaseClass` into a mess of handlers. Here is the approach that I am reluctant to use:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private bool isFoo;

    internal bool IsFoo
    {
        get { return isFoo; }

        private set
        {
            isFoo = value;
            UpdateRequesting(); // Call delegate, similar to INotifyPropertyChanged
        }
    }

    // Private event and delegate.
    private delegate bool OnUpdateRequesting();
    private event OnUpdateRequesting UpdateRequesting;

    internal MyClass()
    {
        // Subscribe to private event inside of constructor.
        UpdateRequesting += UpdateDatabase;
    }

    // Now, raised by event rather than called directly from set accessor.
    private bool UpdateDatabase()
    {
        return DatabaseClass.Update(this);
    }
}
```

Using private events feels like I'm dialing my own phone number. What is the correct way to get `UpdateDatabase()` called without locking properties?

Comment: When `IsFoo` change, you build a Sql command from it, in UI thread, then you can execute at other thread. that way you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` with no problem

Comment: @Sakura : Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` would be nearly identical to the code above. Just replace `OnUpdateRequesting` with `OnPropertyChanged`; however, it would require unnecessary instances of `MyClass` and `PropertyChangedEventArgs`.

Comment: How you use `UpdateRequesting();`? Did you call a function to refresh the UI, or you set value to a control?

Comment: @Sakura : `get { } set { UpdateRequesting() }`

Comment: @Sakura : Typically, the properties get set when the end user clicks a button, or changes a setting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `IsAsync = True` to your `Binding`, and your first approach would work.