# Static Constructor and singleton

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

My friend told me that the following is one of the ways to create `singleton design pattern` in `C#`

```
    public class class1{

    public static class1 Obj { get; private set; }

    static class1()
    {
        Obj = new class1();
    }
}
```

He told me that the static constructor runs only one time in application, so only one instance of `class1` will be created, 
but I see that I have to add this `if(Obj==null)` to check the existence of object

```
      public class class1{

        public static class1 Obj { get; private set; }

        static class1()
        {
            **if(Obj==null)**
            Obj = new class1();
        }
    }
```

which code is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "I see that"? What makes you think you need to? (I would personally use a read-only field, mind you...) See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: The `if` is useless.

Comment: why if is useless? please explain

Comment: @AbrahamJosef Because it is impossible at that step that `Obj` is not null.

Comment: I preffer to use classical singleton pattern with GetInstance() and private constructor. You will no have to think about how c# works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the only place where `Obj` is set is in the `static` constructor, the first code snippet is correct; the second code snippet is redundant.

Since `static` constructors run only once per class. If there is no other path to set `Obj`, its value will always be `null` at the beginning of the `static` constructor. Therefore, the check `if(Obj==null)` will always succeed, which makes it redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The `static constructor` will only ever be called once, at some point prior to the static variables being allocated.
Which means that your friend is correct, you do not need the `if` statement - it is redundant.
This is because you cannot call a `static constructor` manually, it will only be called once, at the start of run-time.

Further reading : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4506997/617485