# How to return a canceled ValueTask<T> that propagates an OperationCanceledException, without async/await?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token, valuetask

I am writting an API that has a [`ValueTask<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1) return type, and accepts a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken). In case the `CancellationToken` is already canceled upon invoking the method, I would like to return a canceled `ValueTask<T>` (`IsCanceled == true`), that propagates an [`OperationCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception) when awaited. Doing it with an async method is trivial:

```
async ValueTask<int> MyMethod1(CancellationToken token)
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    //...
    return 13;
}

ValueTask<int> task = MyMethod1(new CancellationToken(true));
Console.WriteLine($"IsCanceled: {task.IsCanceled}"); // True
await task; // throws OperationCanceledException
```

I decided to switch to a non-[async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) implementation, and now I have trouble reproducing the same behavior. Wrapping a [`Task.FromCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromcanceled) results correctly to a canceled `ValueTask<T>`, but the type of the exception is [`TaskCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception), which is not desirable:

```
ValueTask<int> MyMethod2(CancellationToken token)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        return new ValueTask<int>(Task.FromCanceled<int>(token));
    //...
    return new ValueTask<int>(13);
}

ValueTask<int> task = MyMethod2(new CancellationToken(true));
Console.WriteLine($"IsCanceled: {task.IsCanceled}"); // True
await task; // throws TaskCanceledException (undesirable)
```

Another unsuccessful attempt is to wrap a [`Task.FromException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception). This one propagates the correct exception type, but the task is faulted instead of canceled:

```
ValueTask<int> MyMethod3(CancellationToken token)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        return new ValueTask<int>(
            Task.FromException<int>(new OperationCanceledException(token)));
    //...
    return new ValueTask<int>(13);
}

ValueTask<int> task = MyMethod3(new CancellationToken(true));
Console.WriteLine($"IsCanceled: {task.IsCanceled}"); // False (undesirable)
await task; // throws OperationCanceledException
```

Is there any solution to this problem, or I should accept that my API will behave inconsistently, and sometimes will propagate `TaskCanceledException`s (when the token is already canceled), and other times will propagate `OperationCanceledException`s (when the token is canceled later)?

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p1qOQy).

---

**Update:** As a practical example of the inconsistency I am trying to avoid, here is one from the built-in [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) class:

```
Channel<int> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>();

ValueTask<int> task1 = channel.Reader.ReadAsync(new CancellationToken(true));
await task1; // throws TaskCanceledException

ValueTask<int> task2 = channel.Reader.ReadAsync(new CancellationTokenSource(100).Token);
await task2; // throws OperationCanceledException
```

The first `ValueTask<int>` throws a `TaskCanceledException`, because the token is already canceled. The second `ValueTask<int>` throws an `OperationCanceledException`, because the token is canceled 100 msec later.

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rCkFow).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359129/operationcanceledexception-vs-taskcanceledexception-when-task-is-canceled#comment56461089_34359129?

Comment: @GSerg it may not matter in practical usage, but it matters if you evaluate an API by its consistency. Currently I have two different unit tests for this API, `Assert.ThrowsException<TaskCanceledException>(() =>` for immediate cancellation and `Assert.ThrowsException<OperationCanceledException>(() =>` for delayed cancellation, which looks clunky to say the least.

Comment: You could use an assertion library that can handle matching derived types to the specified exception type.  An example would be xUnit’s Assert.ThrowAny<OperationCancelledException> to handle both of your cases

Comment: @Moho to be honest I am more concerned about my API having inconsistent behavior, and switching to a unit testing library that offers more relaxed assertions is not in my priority list. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach here is probably to simply *have* an `async` helper method you can defer to, here; i.e.:

```cs
ValueTask<int> MyMethod3(CancellationToken token)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return Cancelled(token);
    // ... the rest of your non-async code here

    static async ValueTask<int> Cancelled(CancellationToken token)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // some dummy await, or just suppress the compiler warning about no await
        await Task.Yield(); // should never be reached
        return 0; // should never be reached
    }
}
```

There *is* a third option that might work, but it is a lot more complicated and doesn't avoid allocation (`IValueTaskSource<TResult>` - noting that you'd still need somewhere to stash the relevant token)

Sneakier version:

---

```cs
#pragma warning disable CS1998
static async ValueTask<int> Cancelled(CancellationToken token)
#pragma warning restore CS1998
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    return 0; // should never be reached
}
```

Comment: You would have to question why not just letting this all being async to start with, compiler no allocations free pass, or is there there something I am missing here?

Comment: @TheGeneral in some hot path scenarios, it is genuinely useful to avoid the `async` machinery if it turns out that you *can* answer the query synchronously - and only add that it you *need* to actually `await` something incomplete, or if you need to throw *and* you care about returning a faulted task/valuetask rather than simply throwing on the sync path

Comment: Thanks Marc, this looks promising. My API may throw multiple consecutive exceptions with the same `CancellationToken`. Do you know if it's wise to cache a canceled `ValueTask<T>`, and return the same value to multiple callers?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias absolutely do not ever do that; you must **only** await a `ValueTask<T>` once - behaviour is undefined against multiple awaits, largely due to `IValueTaskSource<TResult>`, and handing out the same value-task to multiple callers would invalidate that. You *can* create a shared `Task<T>` using the same trick, and return a `new ValueTask<int>(GetSharedTask(token))`, however - i.e. the same underlying `Task` is fine

Comment: I tested waiting the same canceled `Task` by multiple threads, and the stack traces were all over the place. I got similar results with what is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534361/throw-same-exception-instance-multiple-times "Throw same exception instance multiple times") question. Wrapping the cached `Task` in a `ValueTask` results to the same mess. So it seems unavoidable that the `Cancelled()` method should be invoked every time. Now I am going to measure how much is the allocation overhead. Hopefully it will be dwarfed by the size of the `Exception` instance.

Comment: [Demo on fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SUZX5E). Shows what happens when a task is awaited concurrently by multiple asynchronous workflows.

Comment: I measured the allocations of the `Cancelled` approach. Running the test in my PC on .NET 5 in Release mode without debugger attached, the allocations per operation are going from 481 bytes to 953 bytes (doubled). As for the duration of each operation, it goes from ~70 μsec to ~140 μsec (also doubled). These results are not very satisfying, but I am accepting your answer anyway because probably no better solution exists. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1m2awI) is the test (the results are different, probably because the Fiddle server runs on debug mode).

Answer (score 0):

Although it throws a `TaskCanceledException` as well, the [ValueTask.FromCanceled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.fromcanceled?view=net-6.0) method has been introduced with .NET 5 and above, which may be relevant here.