# Is it thread safe to modify a nullable DateTimeOffset field without synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Give the following class:

```
public class LockfreeThing
{
    public DateTimeOffset? When { get; private set; }

    public void Work(DateTimeOffset? someOffset)
    {
        var copy = When;
        if (copy.HasValue)
        {
            if (copy > someOffset)
            {
                // Use copy safely
            }
            else
            {
                When = null;
            }
        }

        When = someOffset;
    }
}
```

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209623/is-a-reference-assignment-threadsafe) the reference assignments here are NOT thread safe due to `When` backing field being a `struct`.

Disregarding the possibility of `var copy = When` perhaps reading off of a CPU cache and missing the most up to date value, is it possible to make such code lock-free and thread-safe?

Comment: _"is it possible to make such code lock-free and thread-safe?"_ what part of it? The whole `Work` method? Or only the assignments by themselves?

Comment: Being able to read/write to When (nullable of DateTimeOffset)

Comment: I don't think you can. Just use lock and be done with it.

Comment: It is a structure, not just because it is DateTimeOffset, also because it is nullable.  Updates of structures are never atomic.  Or to put it another way, the processor must use multiple writes to update the value.  And that is never thread-safe, another thread might observe the value when it is only partially updated.  Producing a "torn read".  Very nasty bug to troubleshoot, it doesn't go wrong nearly often enough.  You can't debug bugs that only occur once a month.

Comment: Surely so even a long? and using Ticks wouldn't be possible. Ok so it's simply not possible. Thanks.

Comment: Long you can read with Interlocked. But datetimeoffset is long + short (offset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment to a DateTime is never thread safe (also if it is null).

You could use Ticks instead of DateTime with Int64 and use [Interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) methods to access it.

However what is wrong with using lock?

Comment: Lock will introduce contention and as I'm interested in knowing if there's a 'lock-free' approach for this. I thought about Interlocked though still it can't be nullable as it has the same issue from the OP

Comment: @BrunoGarcia Is that academic interest or do you have a RL usecase?

Comment: Since using Ticks (without nullable) is the closest answer. Considering  the answer being: It's not possible. I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks!