# If a static readonly member calls a static method to get a value, is it done synchronously?

Tags: c#, static, synchronous

Given:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string,int> mydict = CreateDictionary();

    private static Dictionary<string,int> CreateDictionary() { ... }
}
```

Is this done synchronously? (i.e. can two quick instantiations of `MyClass` cause `CreateDictionary()` to be called twice?

Comment: i don't think so.  Should be easy for you to test.  Simply add a random value to the dictionary, and instantiate the class twice.  Then, in both instances, examine the value of the stored item.

Comment: @RussellUhl I'm more concerned about concurrency issues, and I wasn't confident I could set up a race condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's thread safe. [Is the C# static constructor thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/is-the-c-sharp-static-constructor-thread-safe)

> Static constructors are guaranteed to be run only once per application domain, before any instances of a class are created or any static members are accessed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612.aspx

Static field initialization is part of the static constructor. The fact that the field is `readonly` doesn't change anything

Some IL code as requested (taken from Try Roslyn http://goo.gl/ayIMG0)

```
.method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
    void .cctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x205f
    // Code size 11 (0xb)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, int32> MyClass::CreateDictionary()
    IL_0005: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, int32> MyClass::mydict
    IL_000a: ret
} // end of method MyClass::.cctor
```

where `.cctor` is the special name of the static constructors. The call to `CreateDictionary` and the assignment to `mydict` are quite evident.

Comment: But there is no static constructor

Comment: @CriketerOnSO Write a class, put there a static field with a field initializer, compile it, look at it with IlSpy in "IL" mode. You'll see a static constructor with inside the initialization code.

Comment: @CriketerOnSO Or you can look at http://goo.gl/0yMJ68 (using http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: I find that the fact that a static constructor is emitted in this case kind of strange. To quote the spec: "If a static constructor (§10.12) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class.". Also [Eric Lippert's blog post on static constructors](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/14/static-constructors-part-three/) indicates that a static constructor would not be emitted.

Comment: @mikez: I did not intend to imply that no static constructor is emitted; as an implementation detail, yes, a static constructor is emitted. The difference is that the `beforefieldinit` flag is turned on.  As for being "kind of strange", well, the whole feature is kind of strange. I find it bizarre and unfortunate that omitting an empty method can cause a semantic change in a program.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes. I was playing with IL and I just noticed that beforefieldinit flag. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @mike: I know this is splitting semantic hairs, but at the CLI-level there are no static constructors, only type-initializers; static constructors are a C#-level concept. So Eric's blog post is correct: [...]

Comment: @LukeH That then in IL source code are called *cctor* :-) (class-constructor)

Comment: [...] If your C# code has a static constructor then the emitted IL will contain a type-initializer which does the work of that static constructor (and the type will be marked `beforefieldinit`). If your C# code does not have a static constructor then the emitted IL *might* or *might not* contain a type-initializer, depending on static field initialisation etc in your code (and the type will *not* be marked `beforefieldinit`).

Comment: @xanatos: As I said, this is really just semantic nitpicking. The `cctor` is the type-initializer. You won't find the phrase "static constructor" anywhere in the [CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm). Admittedly there's a huge overlap between what type-initializers and static constructors do, but there are subtle differences.

Comment: @LukeH It's a valid point, quite like the argument over whether `~Class` is a "destructor" or a "finallizer". Properly, in C#, it is destructor. The C# spec makes no mention of finalizers (other than in relation to `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers`), while at the runtime level the method is properly called a finalizer. The mistake we me trying to read between the lines about the IL implementation when only behavior was being described in both the C# spec and Eric's post.

Comment: @xanatos It would be nice to add the code generated by the compiler to make the answer better :)

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is correct; the initialization will happen either zero or one times but never twice. But I would add a caveat.  In your example the CLR and the C# language reserve the right to initialize the field *earlier* than you might expect.  If you write:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string,int> mydict = CreateDictionary();
    static MyClass() {}
```

then the CLR and C# guarantee that the field will be initialized when the first static method is called on `MyClass` or when the first instance of `MyClass` is created.  If you omit the static constructor then the CLR and C# are permitted, but not required, to initialize the field at any time *prior* to those events. In particular, suppose you have a method `M` which calls a static method of `MyClass`. The CLR might decide to run the static initializer of `MyClass.mydict` *when `M` is jitted*, and not *when `M` actually calls the static method*.   This can in some rare situations lead to surprising results.

Do a web search on the `beforefieldinit` optimization for more details.  Jon Skeet has a good article on this.

Comment: Would this be an example of something that could lead to different results? http://pastebin.com/v2S4A8gf

Comment: Please, update the link reported in your last comment, since NodaTime is now hosted by GitHub. I think Jon's comments start now at line 897, here: [nodatime/CalendarSystem.cs](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/CalendarSystem.cs)