# Does a static readonly field have only a single copy in memory?

Tags: c#, syntax, static, field, readonly

Does a static readonly field has only a single copy in memory no matter how many objects of its encapsulating type exist?

For example:

```
class A{
  static readonly SomeType foo;
  static A(){
    foo = new SomeType();
  }
...
```

So does `foo` exist only once in the whole program, no matter how many instances of `A` there are?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/is-the-c-sharp-static-constructor-thread-safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) (emphasis mine)

> I.8.4.3 Static fields and static methods
>
> Types
> can
> declare locations that are associated with the type rather than any particular value of
> the type. Such locations are
> static fields
> of the type. As such, static fields declare a location that
> is **shared by all values of the type**. Just like non-static (instance) fields, a static field is typed and
> that type never changes. Static fields are always restricted to a single application domain basis
> (see §
> I.12.5
> ), but they can also be allocated on a per-thread basis.

[ThreadStaticAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows for static allocation on a per-thread basis.

For most usual purposes, there would only be one instance of `SomeType` refrenced by `foo` in your snippet.

If you involve multiple application domains, or decorate it with `[ThreadStatic]`, then multiple instances could possibly exist.

Comment: So just to make sure, since it's shared by all values, it means that it's the same and it's created only once?

Comment: Yes, it is shared by all values of `A`. Are you making a singleton?

Comment: Well I think it's a singleton yes, I need this field to be made only once in the program.

Comment: If you use something like `static readonly Lazy<SomeType> foo = new Lazy<SomeType>(() => new SomeType())`, then later access `foo.Value`, you don't even need the static constructor there. .NET 4+ only.